# Need to fetch the row value when clicking the remove button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing the delete operation in my application. When I click the delete button of the table row ,the bootstrap dialog popup and if I click the delete button of the bootstrap popup the row should get deleted.

I have some how managed to get the popup displayed with the selected 'id' for example if I select the row 1 it tells 'are you sure do you want to delete the student1'.Now I have to click the remove button and It should do the ajax call and the id has to be passed to the flask and based on the id the row has to be deleted.
The problem I am facing here is I cant fetch the the value when I click the remove button.I am including my code here.

Delete button script in the table

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#confirmdeletemodal"
                                data-studentname="{{ each_student.student_name }}" data-href="/{{ each_student.student_id }}" data-toggle="modal">Delete</button>
```

My bootstrap modal

```
 <div class="modal" id="confirmdeletemodal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Remove student?</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-button" type="submit">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

MY script

```
<script>
                // Remove button event trigger
                $('#confirmdeletemodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
                    var triggeringElement = $(e.relatedTarget);
                    console.log("Triggering element is: ",triggeringElement.data('href'));
                    $(this).find('#remove-button').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                    console.log("This is in confirmdelete" + $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                    var modal = $(this)
                    modal.find('.modal-body').text('Are you sure you wish to delete this '+ triggeringElement.data("studentname") + 'student? ')

                })
            </script>

            <script>
                $("#remove-button").click(function(e){
                    var triggeringElement = $(e.relatedTarget);
                    $(this).find('#remove-button').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                    var jobid = triggeringElement.data('href');
                    console.log("I am inside the remove button" ,$(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'/delete',
                        data:{'student-id':$(e.relatedTarget).data('href')},
                        success:function(result){
                            var msg="This user is deleted";
                            ("#resultDiv").html(msg);
                        }
                    })

                })
            </script>
```

The actual result I am getting here is in the below line I am getting undefined error for the $(e.relatedTarget).data('href')

```
console.log("I am inside the remove button" ,$(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
```

The expected output is
I have to get the value of the studentid

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself and the solution is I dont need to create a separate script for remove button click and it worked.